# How to retrieve private key from RSA machine level container?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

How to retrieve private key from RSA machine level container using C#?
I've created a RSA key with

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pc "MyKeys2" -exp
```

Now I want to use that key to encrypt my data, here's the code so far:

```
CspParameters cspParam = new CspParameters();
cspParam.KeyContainerName = "MyKeys2";
cspParam.Flags |= CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;

RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParam);

var keyFromContainer = rsa.ToXmlString(true);//Here throws exception "Key not valid for use in specified state."
```

But when I try to retrieve the key throws exception "Key not valid for use in specified state."
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To manage this issue add user who is running the application with following:

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "ContainerName" "UserName"
```